# jQuery highlight on settimeout

Tags: jquery, settimeout, highlight

I have this script:

```
function nudge(){
$("#info").animate({left:"+=5px"},40).animate({top:"+=5px"},40).animate({top:"-=10px"},40).animate({left:"-=10px"},40)
    .animate({top:"+=5px"},40).animate({left:"+=5px"},40)
    .animate({left:"+=5px"},40).animate({top:"+=5px"},40).animate({top:"-=10px"},40).animate({left:"-=10px"},40)
    .animate({top:"+=5px"},40).animate({left:"+=5px"},40)
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#info").effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
    }, 1000);
```

}

I want the div to be highlighted after the animate, but now I think the set of the highlight effect is not right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function nudge(){
$("#info").animate({left:"+=5px"},40).animate({top:"+=5px"},40).animate({top:"-=10px"},40).animate({left:"-=10px"},40)
    .animate({top:"+=5px"},40).animate({left:"+=5px"},40)
    .animate({left:"+=5px"},40).animate({top:"+=5px"},40).animate({top:"-=10px"},40).animate({left:"-=10px"},40)
    .animate({top:"+=5px"},40).animate({left:"+=5px"},40)
        .delay(1000) // same as setTimeout 1000
        .animate({top:"+=5px"}, 0, function(){ // dummy animate for callback
            $("#info").effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
        });
}
```